# PCB Design Review (KiCAD)

Tags: pcb, audio, kicad

I'm still a beginner at PCB design so I wanted to get any feedback on my PCB. The project I'm working on is for a DIY Pocket Operator, there are some pushbuttons/LED's, a Teensy 3.2/Audio shield, a LiPo battery, and a small OLED. The teensy/shield will attach to the header pins and the battery will connect to the JST connector; the OLED connects to the 4 pin connector and the other header pins are for breaking out IO.

One thing I wasn't sure about was the trace widths; the signals are fairly low current (<10mA), so from my calculations the trace width should be sufficient but should I go larger on the traces?

I'm not sure what the best way to post my design is, but I've included the schematic, images of the 3D view, and plots of the copper layers. Let me know if there's a better way for people to review my design.

Thanks!

3D View:

[image: https://ibb.co/ysxqkSk]

[image: https://ibb.co/vhYCjr5]

PCB:

https://ibb.co/hYKFrJ7

https://ibb.co/6sbXrF5

https://ibb.co/gSRVjmv

https://ibb.co/qLHywxj

https://ibb.co/3FjZFpg

https://ibb.co/8d0bTKS

https://ibb.co/r6pL1hg

https://ibb.co/WzNzbX0

https://ibb.co/9y6Wywy

Schematic:

https://ibb.co/PN43Ftj

Comment: It would be good for viewability to add the images directly to your post, as I have done for two examples. Usually begin with the schematic, as that should convey the logical idea / plan. Then show layout.

Comment: I am not a fan of "blackbox" schematic symbols such as you use for IC1 and IC2 and the switches. the problem is that these don't convey anything, and therefore fail at probably the most important task of the schematic drawing. Its better to use descriptive symbols, and ideally sub parts if applicable.

Comment: For GND it is more conventional to use a down-pointing GND symbol and not a GND netlabel. Consider decoupling caps at the muxes.

Comment: A screenshot or image of the KiCad PCB editor view would be more readable than the black and white fabrication outputs.

Comment: Decoupling capacitors?

Comment: Also, if you plan to access the Teensy's USB port once plugged in, check that it isn't blocked by the headers.

Comment: Comparing the hole and pad size of J1 to J2 and J5, they look a bit small for what is supposedly "normal" 2.54mm pin headers. Also, I try to add diode symbol next to LEDs (just one if they're all the same orientation) so I know which way round to populate them if doing manual PnP. Decoupling caps (say, 1uF) next to the power pin of each IC